# awful disorganized table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the following table with which i've been struggling to make look better but unsuccessfully. The text is unaligned vertically row by row, it has lots of blank spaces that I would like to cover. I will be adding more text but not until I create a better looking and more appealing table.  I'm not sure it it looks this way because of the figures or just because of my clumsiness to work with tables in latex.The code for the table is aso a mess and makes working on the table really confusing. I would grateful if[image] someone could help.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
{\bf Model} & {\bf Main characteristics} & {\bf Mounted} & {\bf Folded} & {\bf Advantages and disadvantages}          \\ \hhline{=|=|=|=|=}

Blix vika+ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}350W rear hub\\ Frame folds horizontally\\ Folds head tube and pedals\\ Wheels side by side but unaligned\end{tabular} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/vika1.jpg} & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/vika+f.jpg}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Easy to fold\\ Not very compact\\ Hard to transport when folded\end{tabular}   \\ \hline

Volt Metro     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}250W rear hub\\ Frame folds horizontally\\ Folds head tube and pedals\\ Wheells alligned but not in parallel\end{tabular}  &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/volt.jpg} &    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/voltmetro.jpg}      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Easy to fold\\ Not very compact\\ Hard to transport when folded\end{tabular}                   \\ \hline

Gi Flybike     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}250W rear hub\\ Frame folds vertically\\ Wheels in parallel when folded\end{tabular}         &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/gifly.jpg}        &   \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/giflyf.jpg}         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fast and easy to fold\\ Trolley\\ Low moving parts\\ Not very compact\\ Practical\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Mando Footlose & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}250W rear hub\\ Hybrid\\ Frame folds vertically\\ Folds head tube\end{tabular} &  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/mando.jpg}  &     \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/mandof.jpg}     & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Fast and easy to fold\\ Trolley\\ Low moving parts\\ Not very compact\\ Practical\end{tabular} \\ \hline

Go cycle       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}250W front hub\\ Folds chainstay vertically \\ Folds head tube and seat\\ To fold completely it's necessary\\ to remove the wheels\end{tabular} &    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/gocycle.jpg}        &   \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/gocyclef.jpg}        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Practical \\ Few moving parts \\ Hard to transport when folded\end{tabular}                    \\ \hline

Jivr Bike      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}350W front hub\\ Folds chainstay vertically\\ Front frame folds horizontally\\ Chainless\end{tabular}                                         &    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/jivr.jpg}       &     \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/jivrf.jpg}       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Very compact\\ Several moving parts\\ Hard to transport when folded\end{tabular}               \\ \hline

Weelin         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Power?? central motor\\ Folds chainstay vertically \\ Folds head tube, seat and pedalls\end{tabular}                                          &    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/weelin.jpg}      &       \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Figures/weelinf.jpg}    & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Very compact\\ Several moving parts\\ Hard to transport when folded\end{tabular}               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: Well, to be absolutely honest, I think your table looks great.

Comment: the main thing you are doing wrong is aligning the base of the images with the centre of the text. Either top align them all or centre them all. You have not provided a usable example but you appear to be using the adjustbox package which gives `\includegraphics` an option to vertically centre.

Comment: thanks for the help. The table looks better already. How do I manage the images vertical alignment in the table? or the alignment of a specific cell of the table

Comment: To center an image use \raisebox{-0.5\height}{...}

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Above image is obtained by:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,
            margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell,hhline,tabularx}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\setlength\hsize{0.6\hsize}}L|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{1.2\hsize}}L|
                                c|c|
                              >{\setlength\hsize{1.2\hsize}}L|}
\hline
\thead{Model} 
    &   \thead{Main\\ characteristics} 
        &   \thead{Mounted} 
            & \thead{Folded} 
                & \thead{Advantages and\\ disadvantages}          
                                                    \\  \hhline{=|=|=|=|=}
Blix vika+ 
    &   350W rear hub\newline 
        Frame folds horizontally\newline 
        Folds head tube and pedals\newline 
        Wheels side by side but unaligned
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt] {Figures/vika1.jpg}
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt] {Figures/vika+f.jpg}
                &   Easy to fold\newline  
                    Not very compact\newline 
                    Hard to transport when folded   \\ \hline
Volt Metro     
    &   250W rear hub\newline  
        Frame folds horizontally\newline  
        Folds head tube and pedals\newline  
        Wheells alligned but not in parallel
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/volt.jpg} 
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/voltmetro.jpg}
                &   Easy to fold\newline  
                    Not very compact\newline  
                    Hard to transport when folded   \\ \hline
Gi Flybike     
    &   250W rear hub\newline  
        Frame folds vertically\newline   
        Wheels in parallel when folded
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/gifly.jpg}        
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/giflyf.jpg}
                &   Fast and easy to fold\newline  
                    Trolley\newline   
                    Low moving parts\newline  
                    Not very compact\newline  
                    Practical                           \\ \hline
Mando Footlose 
    &   250W rear hub\newline  
        Hybrid\newline  
        Frame folds vertically\newline  
        Folds head tube
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/mando.jpg}  
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/mandof.jpg}
                &   Fast and easy to fold\newline  
                    Trolley\newline  
                    Low moving parts\newline  
                    Not very compact\newline  
                    Practical                           \\ \hline
Go cycle       
    &   250W front hub\newline  
        Folds chainstay vertically\newline  
        Folds head tube and seat\newline  
        To fold completely it's necessary remove the wheels
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/gocycle.jpg}        
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/gocyclef.jpg}
                &   Practical\newline  
                    Few moving parts\newline  
                    Hard to transport when folded       \\ \hline
Jivr Bike      
    &   350W front hub\newline  
        Folds chainstay vertically\newline  
        Front frame folds horizontally\newline  
        Chainless
        &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/jivr.jpg}       
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/jivrf.jpg}
                &   Very compact\newline  
                    Several moving parts\newline  
                    Hard to transport when folded           \\ \hline
Weelin         
    &   Power?? central motor\newline  
        Folds chainstay vertically\newline  
        Folds head tube, seat and pedalls                                          &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/weelin.jpg}      
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/weelinf.jpg}
                &   Very compact\newline  
                    Several moving parts\newline  
                    Hard to transport when folded           \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For vertical positioning of images and for margins above and below them I exploit `adjustbox` package, instead `tabular` I rather use `tabularx`. Its benefits are obvious: useing `X` column type make nested tabulars surplus and with simple redefinition with `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` the cells contents are vertically centered.

**Addendum:**
Maybe you will find attractive to list features of showed bikes with `itemize environment (tested only in last row of table):

[image]

For such presentation of bike's features you need to add in preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}               % <-- added, for show itemize of bikes features
    \newcommand{\tablistcmd}{\leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
    \setlist{nosep, %topsep=0pt, partopsep=0pt,
             leftmargin=*,
             before=\tablistcmd, after=\tablistcmd%
             }
```

and change table as you can see in case of the last table row:

```
Weelin         
    &   \begin{itemize}
        \item   Power central motor 
        \item   Folds chainstay vertically 
        \item   Folds head tube, seat and pedals
        \end{itemize}                                          &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/weelin.jpg}
            &   \includegraphics[width=20mm,height=25mm,valign=M,margin=0pt 5pt]  {Figures/weelinf.jpg}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                    \item   Very compact
                    \item   Several moving parts
                    \item   Hard to transport when folded
                    \end{itemize}                           \\ \hline
```